# Is the xassoccnt package still maintained?

Tags: packages, maintenance

The homepage listed on https://ctan.org/pkg/xassoccnt?lang=de is currently an empty webpage, when trying to reach the author via e-mail I only get the automated response "No LaTeX support any longer by me...".

Comment: Christian recently posted on a popular social media site that he's leaving all such platforms (including TeX-sx) ...

Comment: @JosephWright At least he could set the package state to "unmaintained". Instead it's still author-maintained which means nobody else can become the maintainer of this package. Another dead-end package. Great :-(

Comment: Some maintainers read emails and bug reports and still decide to ignore them. Christian stays a bit under the radar, that does not mean he never comes back. One should never judge prematurely.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt It's possible to fork such a project (see `etoolbox`, `biblatex`, ...), but I have suggested to Frank that we might want to address that in the LPPL ...

Comment: Just yesterday, the package was updated on ctan from 1.6 to 1.6a

Comment: Indeed, see http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-June/006688.html or http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=47976. But I fail to see any code changes ...

Comment: I will update the package one day, but not in near future. Consider the package as "broken" concerning "caption".

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your feedback. No problem, I will implement a work-around in `totalcount` instead.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: That's another possibility, of course, but my package still needs a fix then. Unfortunately my job takes a lot of time recently, so there's not much TeX support.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I try to update the documentation and release version 3.4 of the `caption` package for years, so unfortunately I know what you are talking about. Please no stress about this issue, family (and job) first.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: I referred to TeX (well package) support from my side in near future. It's my fault and I have to fix it, but as I wrote, I am short of time...